# Show first value in year axis, regardless of what month graph starts on

Tags: d3.js

**test_data.csv**:

```
date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575
```

**page.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 -->
<style>

</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");


var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range(["#CE1126", "#00B6D0"]); // red and blue 

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month

var xYearAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                  .ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
                  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // label every year

// load .csv file
d3.csv("test_data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data){
    if (error) throw error;

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        //console.log(parseDate(d.date));
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
    var barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(data.length+1);     

    data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });


    x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );

    var max = x.domain()[1];
    var min = x.domain()[0];
    var datePlusOneMonth = d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1), -1); // last day of current month: move up one month, back one day 

    x.domain([min,datePlusOneMonth]);

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);


    // the bars 
    g.append("g")
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; })
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", barWidth);


    // x-axis
    var axis = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    var yearAxis = g.append("g")
                     .attr("class", "axis")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
                     .call(xYearAxis);

    axis.selectAll("g").select("text")
      .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");

});
</script>

</body>
```

**Current output**:

[image]

What I am looking for is to add `2012` to the very first tick in the year axis. More generally, I am looking into eventually building a filter based on a slider into this project - so the more general problem I'd like to solve is this: regardless of what month appears at the very left of the graph, I would like for the year to appear in the tick under the graph. How can I do this?

Looking at the [`scaleTime` documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleTime), it appears that `scaleTime` ticks are primarily made to be uniformly spaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply, add this two strings before your `yearAxis` variable:

```
const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0]; 
xYearAxis.tickValues([firstDataYear].concat(x.ticks()));

var yearAxis = g.append("g") // ...
```

It the first string we store the first date item to `firstDataYear` variable. And in the second you concat this variable with default set of ticks that you can get with `x.ticks()` method. Check working demo in the hidden snippet below (I rewrote ajax request to `d3.csvParse` to simplify the example):

```js
var dataAsCsv = `date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575`;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");


var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range(["#CE1126", "#00B6D0"]); // red and blue 

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month

var xYearAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                  .ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
                  .tickValues(x.ticks())
                  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // label every year



var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv, function(d, i, columns) {
   for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
})

data.forEach(function(d) {
  //console.log(parseDate(d.date));
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
var barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(data.length+1);     

data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });


x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );

var max = x.domain()[1];
var min = x.domain()[0];
var datePlusOneMonth = d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1), -1); // last day of current month: move up one month, back one day 

x.domain([min,datePlusOneMonth]);

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
z.domain(keys);


// the bars 
g.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
  .attr("width", barWidth);


// x-axis
var axis = g.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0]
xYearAxis.tickValues([firstDataYear].concat(x.ticks()));

var yearAxis = g.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
.call(xYearAxis);

axis.selectAll("g").select("text")
  .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```